# How to send end-of-file through a pipe without closing the pipe?

Tags: c, pipe

When I open a terminal running bash and type the following:

```
cat\nfoo\n^Decho bar\n
```

(where \n is enter and ^D is control-d) I get:

```
foo
bar
```

Ie, ^D causes cat to exit, but I can still type more.
How would I send the same input (specifically the end-of-file) through a (unix) pipe in C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xterm` does not perform its input with the shell and utilities via `pipe(7)`s. Instead, it uses the Unix PTY framework (see `pty(7)`, `openpty(3)`, `forkpty(3)`, `posix_openpt(3)`, `pts(4)` manpages for some information). The PTY framework allows any process to serve as a terminal "master" (e.g., `telnetd(8)`, `sshd(8)`, `xterm(1)`, etc.) and any process can connect to the terminal slave to provide an interactive environment just like sitting at the console.

The [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd edition](http://www.apuebook.com/) book by [Stevens and Rago](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433079) has an excellent chapter on using pseudo-terminal devices to control slave programs -- including an excellent little `pty` program that allows driving "interactive" programs in a manner similar to `expect(1)`, but in C rather than `tcl`.

Comment: ... wow, I really forget how broken unix is when everything else is even worse. +1, hopefully beating pty into a semi-working pipe interface wont be too hard.

Answer (score 3):

Control-D is special to the terminal, not to general input. Simply close the pipe.

Comment: No, I mean how do I cause the process reading from the pipe currently to read a EOF, but then continue to write to it (like /usr/bin/xterm does)?

Comment: The only way to cause the reader to receive an EOF error is for the file to be at the end; pipes never end until all possible writers have closed their access to it. EOF is not a character that's read, it's a state of the file.

Comment: Then how does /usr/bin/xterm (and other terminal emulators) send EOF to its subprocesses?

Comment: @DavidX: They close the pipe. Closing the pipe sends EOF to readers.

Comment: I'm using Perl IO::Pty:Easy to make my pty, and it only gives me API to close the pty. How can I get it to signal to the child that it has stopped providing input so that it can exit cleanly rather than killing the child as `$pty->close()` does? It doesn't seem like `$pty->write()` provides the ability to close it.

Comment: @StevenLu you should start a new post with this question. As a comment here, it's not going to get any timely attention from someone able to answer you, but as a new posted question you've got a good chance to get an answer.

Comment: @mah Well, i have [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117896/termreadkey-non-blocking-read-in-raw-mode-detect-eof).