# how to send EOF to a process in python

Tags: c, eof

Now I have a program like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    char str[200];
    while(read(0, str,10)>0){
        printf("%s", str);
    }   
    printf("good\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

When receive EOF, this program will print `good` and then go on accepting my next input and then print it out in case of run directly.

What I what to do is interact with it with another python code:

```
from pwn import *

r = process('./test')
r.send('123')
print r.recv(1000)
r.send('\x04')
print r.recv(1000)
```

But not matter how, I can't get out of the while loop unless I shutdown the connection. But I won't be able to send the last input if I shutdown the connection.
I found it somewhere that '\x04' stands for EOF. But it seems not working.

I wonder what I should to do to get out of the loop and then send the last input.

Comment: Just an aside, but your `str` buffer in your C program is not getting null terminated. Make sure you set `str[N]='\0'` after each `read` call.

Comment: `EOF` is *not* a `char` (so one cannot "send" it). It is a state. `read()` *detects* "End-Of-File" if and when the input stream got closed. You might want to invent a different protocol.

Comment: "When receive EOF, this program will print good and then go on accepting my next input" - When you encounter EOF, the is no "next input".

Comment: But you can test this: when ^D is pressed, it prints "good" and waits for my next input if I run it manually

Comment: You know EOF means end of file, right?  It's very unusual to design your program to use an EOF as a record separator, because it can't actually be stored in a file.  Why not use a newline?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send end-of-file through a pipe without closing the pipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720947/how-to-send-end-of-file-through-a-pipe-without-closing-the-pipe)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've just got stdin and stdout streams to communicate with your test process.  This isn't enough to send EOF, you need a PTY.  You can use ptyprocess for this:

```
from ptyprocess import PtyProcessUnicode
p = PtyProcessUnicode.spawn(['./test'])
p.write("123\n")
print(p.read())
p.sendeof()
print(p.read())
```